# Making UITableView section header overlap the first cell of the section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is it possible to apply an offset to the section header views of a `tableview` similar to the way we can apply an inset to the tableview content?

I'm trying to achieve a similar thing that you can see in the Google Calendar for iOS app (See the attached screenshots).

See how the day marks on the left (`{15, Tue}`, `{16, Wed}`) is floating the same way a section header floats, and in addition its not starting **above** the first cell of the section, but in the same y position as the first cell in the section.

I'm using the `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` delegate method, and I'm getting the header via the `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:` of the tableview.
I'm creating the view using `InterfaceBuilder`.

**UPDATE**
Ok, I've manage to get closer. I've noticed that when I'm not implementing the `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` method, I almost get the exact behaviour I'm after - except I lose the normal behaviour of section headers (of one section header pushing the previous one out of the screen when it touches it).

[Update screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyzOm.png)
[Update screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW6Pd.png)

As you can see on `Update screenshot 1` the appearance is the requested one. Unfortunately, scrolling up a bit revealed I'm not yet there, as you can see in `Update screenshot 2` - The headers overlaps each other, and the top one disappears when the bottom one reach to the same spot (instead of being pushed out).

It makes sense though, as both have zero height (since I haven't implemented the relevant delegate method, as I've mentioned earlier)

**UPDATE 2**
It seems I can't get to the exact behaviour without losing something in the way. I can get the section headers behaviour (each header pushing out the previous) but doing so I'm unable to remove the empty space of header size (returned in `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`).
On the other hand, I can remove the empty space, and get the section header to overlap the first cell, but doing so I also lose the normal section header behaviour (because they don't have a real height - you can see in the screenshot I've added in the previous update).

***Original screenshots***

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Screenshot 3]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be possible. For this you need to take one UIView which will have clear background and only one label on left side as we see in picture. we make the height of this UIView bit more which will then overlap approx. the first row in a section and the Label in this UIView will be Vertically center. We will return this UIView to viewForHeaderInSection of UITableview.
Hope this may help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm creating the view in IB using a xib. I tried your suggestion and I am able to make the header overlap the first raw and maintain the section header behaviour (of the next header pushing the previous one when scrolling), but I'm left with an empty space of a size as big as returned in `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`. Any thoughts on how to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

*I doubt this answer will still be useful to you, but maybe it will help others.*

I tried to implement this behavior in the same way as you and, of course, I faced the same issues…

After some searches, I found the beginning of a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58302041). [Xuan-Gieng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5371131/xuan-gieng-nguyen) suggests using the scrollView's offset of the table view and passing it to the cells. So I used a UITableView without headers and I grouped the events of a same day into a UIStackView. A cell represents a day rather than an event, and the day number is at the top left of the cell view.

The top constraint of the day view has a priority of 750 and the bottom constraint has a "Greater Than or Equal" relation.

[image]

The code is pretty straightforward after that!

**ViewController:**

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "EventsTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "EventsCell")
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame = CGRect.zero
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EventsCell") as? EventsTableViewCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        cell.dayLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.section)"
        cell.updateDayConstraint(scrollPosition: 0) // To reset the constraint
        return cell
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if let cell = tableView.visibleCells.first {
            if let c = cell as? EventsTableViewCell {
                let position = scrollView.convert(scrollView.contentOffset, to: c).y
                c.updateDayConstraint(scrollPosition: position)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**EventsTableViewCell:**

```
class EventsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var dayLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dayTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    func updateDayConstraint(scrollPosition: CGFloat) {
        if scrollPosition > 0 {
            dayTopConstraint.constant = scrollPosition + 8
        } else {
            dayTopConstraint.constant = 8 // Default constraint
        }
    }

}
```