# How to Scroll content of cell into another cell in tableview like Google Calendar did?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll

I wants user interface into tableview like Google calendar did. It is showing same dates events in different rows but when you scroll up or down, the date in left side gets scroll up down too.

Can you please help me how to achieve this. Please take a look on screenshot.[image]

As i am thinking this can be achieve by using tableview. If i am wrong then happy to follow your suggetion.

Answer (score 1):

I personal think it can be achieved using tableView.

One way to do it is to calculate the scrollView's offset of the table view and pass it to the cell so that it update the top constraint for the date view.

Another way is to set up the constraint follow this idea. I didn't try but I think it could work as well.

[image]

Comment: Yes that is correct but let's say each of my cell has that date portion. If there are multiple events with same date then i will only show date in first cell. Also if i move that date along with scrollview offset then how it will work for next cell ? If possible can you please provides me any programming guide about this.

Comment: Please check this link of my implementation.https://drive.google.com/file/d/18-PLyWLT8WUFGGhrMe5TB7ns2GGr9Fem/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Actually one cell is not just having 1 event. In my opinion, 1 cell is for 1 day and we can have multiple events on the same day.

Comment: Ok then you mean should i go with tableview inside tableview correct ? Root tableview is for days and inside tableview will be for events display.

Comment: Yes, I think you can either go with a vertical stack view or a nested table view. Depends on your complexity :)

Comment: Based on your suggestions, I implemented this behavior. Here is my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67582270/6748318